# Can I share a single pull resistor on multiple enable pins to save space?

Tags: resistors, pullup, pulldown

I am using this Schmidt trigger IC [SN74HCS125](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hcs125.pdf?ts=1595634116803&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN74HCS125) which has 4 channels

I would like to save some board space by hopefully using only one resistor to pull down the enable pins of each channel. I do not plan to connect those enable pins to anything else as I want them to be always enabled.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg1Tsrm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have not done this before since what I have been doing since now was individually giving them their own resistor. Just intuitively speaking it should work, but there might be caveats that I am not aware of. Is doing this perfectly fine?

Comment: You do not need a resistor as they are meant to be directly grounded (ON), or tied to Vcc (OFF). If you insist on R1 then keep it under 1 Kohms.

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy Why should the resistor be less than 1k? What bad thing would happen if the resistor is 2.2k?

Comment: [Page 8 Section 8.3.1 last paragraph last sentence](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hcs125.pdf?ts=1595634116803&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN74HCS125#page=8) did mention of tying it to a pull up/down resistor. Im also curious why about under 1K ohms ? Any reason for that? Is it a general rule or a value specific to this IC ?

Comment: That paragraph is referring to using a pull-up or -down on the output, so that it goes to a defined state when disabled instead of floating.

Comment: Resistors are not needed to set a static state for CMOS inputs. Bipolar (TTL) inputs need resistors to avoid drawing too much current.  Since CMOS inputs are basically open circuit at DC, a resistor is unnecessary.  You could use a resistor just so that you can easily leave it out if you are patching in new logic, instead of cutting traces or lifting pins.

Comment: Sorry, thanks to @crj11 for adding clarification to my comment. You are using CMOS 74HCxxx series which does not need a resistor, but as mentioned in comments the old 74LSxxx series does as each input pin outputs a few uA of current. 1 K to 2.2 K is fine.

Comment: @crj11 I see would make sense since cmos are made fets and fets dont use current on the gate but voltages. So the resistors are just unnecessary.

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy How did you know that the enable pins are CMOS, all that i could find are only on the inputs and outputs. Since the inputs and outputs are CMOS its safe to assume that the enabl are also build using CMOS?

Comment: @Jake quin: Use 1K pull-down common to all OE# signals. This resister is necessary. "since cmos are made fets and fets dont use current on the gate but voltages" - you need to read more fets also use current but in a different way. No CMOS input should be left open (with out default state)

Comment: @Jakequin I have worked with these ICs for several decades. 74HCxxx is all CMOS, both inputs and outputs. I would have grounded those OE pins and moved onto ten other issues by now.

Answer (score 2):

The unused inputs can be directly connected to ground (or supply voltage). It even reads in the datasheet.